# How do I Reboot BG96 with AT command

Tags: at-command

I tried rebooting BG96 by `AT+NRB` at command but it's not working. What is the AT command for rebooting the BG96 board exactly?

Comment: I vote to reopen because this question **IS NOT** about HW. The OP is asking for an AT command to obtain a specific result. Though it is something agnostic from the programming perspective, at-commands is a tag with more than a thousand questions, because it is a set of command that can be provided through a serial interface to a modem using whatever language you like on host side.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - The question has been reopened, so you can post that as an answer now.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I just noticed the [_meta effect_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403258/11336762). I expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Even though `+NRB` is the correct command for performing a reboot on modules such as [BC95](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_BC95_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.9.pdf), it doesn't appear to be supported on BG96 modules.

According to [BG96 AT commands guide](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_BG96_AT_Commands_Manual_V2.1.pdf), the reset can be performed by means of `+CFUN` command:

```
AT+CFUN=1,1
```

In fact, the syntax of the write command is

```
AT+CFUN=<fun>[,<rst>]
```

where the second parameter `<rst>` is described as follows:

> **`<rst>`:**
> **0** - Do not reset the ME before setting it to functionalitylevel.This is the defaultsettingwhenis not given.
> **1** - Reset the ME. The device is fully functional after the reset. This value is available only for <fun>=1.

---

Please note how the described command **doesn't** work on BC95, where the following note is reported:

> `<rst>` is not supported and will be ignored

I can assume that `+NRB` was supported just to provide for the limitations of `+CFUN` on that product.